# Subset a distance matrix in R by values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, distance, symmetric

I have a very large distance matrix (3678 x 3678) currently encoded as a data frame. Columns are named "1", "2", "3" and so on, the same for rows. So what I need to do is to find values <26 and different from 0 and to have the results in a second dataframe with two columns: the first one with index and the second one with the value. For example:

```
            value
318-516   22.70601
...
```

where 318 is the row index and 516 is the column index.

Comment: Hi Nancy, it sounds like you're asking about a [distance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix) so I edited your question to provide some clarity. Please let me know if this was your intent and the question still makes sense as you intended it!

Comment: @Dubukay yes thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm trying to recreate your situation (note: if you can, it's always helpful to include a few lines of your data with a `dput` command).

You should be able to use `filter` and some simple tidyverse commands (if you don't know how they work, run them line by line, always selecting commands up to the `%>%` to check what they are doing):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidylog) # gives you additional output on what each command does
# Creating some data that looks similar
data <- matrix(rnorm(25,mean = 26),ncol=5)
data <- as_tibble(data)
data <- setNames(data,c(1:5))

data %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "column",values_to = "values", names_prefix = "V") %>% 
  # depending on how your column names look like, you might need to use a separate() command first
  filter(values > 0 & values < 26) %>% 
  
  # if you want you can create an index column as well
  mutate(index = paste0(row,"-",column)) %>% 
  
  # then you can get rid of the row and column
  select(-row,-column) %>% 
  # move index to the front
  relocate(index)
```

Comment: this works, but my col names are V1, V2, V3 and so on...is it possible to remove the V and to have only numbers?

Comment: Yes, you simply need to add `names_prefix = "V"` to the `pivot_longer()` command. Put together:  `pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "column",values_to = "values", names_prefix = "V") %>% `
I'll edit this in the answer as well - if this resolved it, would you mind accepting the answer by chance? :)

Comment: hello, and what if my data are encoded as a large matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean with the encoding as a large matrix - but you could try converting the matrix to a `data.frame` or `tibble` using `as.data.frame()` or `as_tibble()`.